# How to click a button and trigger something then open an URL in a new tab

Tags: visualforce

I wonder how to have a button in VF page which will trigger some apex code and then open a URL with a new window tab.

Below is my idea, is it doable in VF page with a dedicate controller?

Thanks so much

## VF page

```
<apex:page id="PortalTemplateInstallRedirect" controller="PortalInstaller" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton onclick="DoSomethingAndOpenANewTab(); return false;"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:page>
```

## PortalInstaller

```
public void DoSomethingAndOpenANewTab(){

    // deploy data to database
    // open a new tab with a fixed url

}
```

I found all solutions are about using JS to open a new tab but which doesn't run an apex method

The below approach could not meet my requirement :(
`window.open('https://c.cs8.visual.force.com/apex/Mobiles?id={!Campaign.Id}','_blank');`

Comment: I would suggest to go through some trailheads on this basic functionality

Comment: @SantanuBoral Is my idea doable? Because I found all solutions is about using js to open a new tab but which doesn't involve the custom apex method

Answer (score 1):

You need action and oncomplete attribute here. action is used to call controller(Apex) method and oncomplete is used to call another JS method when current execution is complete.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!ControllerMethodName}" value="Save" oncomplete="DoSomethingAndOpenANewTab(); return false;"/>
```

If you want to add any checks then you can add them.